# How to convert rows into columns in oracle into particular set of columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

I have a table in which there are 2 columns. I want to convert the rows into sets of 4 columns.
For example, the table I have:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | N |
| 2 | N |
| 3 | N |
| 4 | N |
| 5 | N |

I want to transpose them as:

| Column1 | Columnn2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | N | N | N |
| N | N |  |  |

How can I do this in Oracle?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where does the third row come from?  It is not in the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (col1, col2) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select 1, 'N' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'N' from dual union all
  6     select 3, 'N' from dual union all
  7     select 4, 'N' from dual union all
  8     select 5, 'N' from dual
  9    ),
 10  temp as
 11    -- union of two columns will produce a single-column "table"
 12    (select to_char(col1) col from test union all
 13     select col2              from test
 14    ),
 15  temp2 as
 16    -- ordinal numbers for each row
 17    (select col,
 18            row_number() over (order by null) rn
 19     from temp
 20    ),
 21  temp3 as
 22    -- a little bit of calculation so that you'd be able to create groups of 4 columns
 23    (select col,
 24            mod(rn, 4) rn,
 25            ceil(rn / 4) grp
 26     from temp2
 27    )
 28  -- final query
 29  select max(case when rn = 1 then col end) col1,
 30         max(case when rn = 2 then col end) col2,
 31         max(case when rn = 3 then col end) col3,
 32         max(case when rn = 0 then col end) col4
 33  from temp3
 34  group by grp;
```

---

```
COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4
----- ----- ----- -----
1     2     3     4
5     N     N     N
N     N

SQL>
```